# Hide div when Save/Open box appears

Tags: javascript, jquery, download

I have a page with a list of mp3 urls.  When you click on a specific item it fires off this javascript to download the mp3 file.

```
$(document).on('click', "a.item", function(e) {
    var a_href = ($(this).closest('li').find('a.item').attr('href'));
   e.preventDefault();  
   window.location.assign('download.php?q='+a_href);
});
```

this goes to a separate page (download.php) with this code:

```
 $file= $_GET['q'];
 header("Content-Type: audio/mp3");
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=audio.mp3"); 
 echo file_get_contents($file);
```

This works great and gives me the save or open dialog box.  The problem is that the file may take a long time to get the contents, and so I can put a loading image up when the click occurs, but I need a way to identify when the save or open dialog box appears (so I can stop the loading image).  Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Do you want to stop the loading image when the save/open dialog box appear?

Comment: yes, exactly..thats what I need to do

Comment: Use the 'beforeunload' event to detect it.